# How can I display title of post in a separate page on Angular app?

Tags: angular

I'm already prepared routing for each post, depending on his index.

You can see on a screenshot #2 that URL is dynamical.
I need to display a title of selected post on a opened page

Here is the link to repository https://github.com/paslavskyi9roman/Freecher

```
<div
  class="post"
  *ngFor="let post of posts; let i = index"
  [attr.data-index]="i"
>
  <a [title]="post.title" [routerLink]="['/post/', i]">
    <div class="title">
      <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
      <span>Posted by: {{ post.author }}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
      <p>{{ post.text }}</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

[Here is my home page of application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KteP4.png)

[here is a page of selected Post.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GUlU.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add id in your Post interface:

```
export interface Post {
    id: number,
    title: string,
    text: string,
    author: string,
}
```

then add id in your mock-post.ts:

```
export const POSTS: Post[] = [
    {id:1, title: 'Post 1', text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. ', author: 'Nickname'},
    ...
    ...
    ...
    {id:8, title: 'Post21', text: 'lorem 3 text', author: 'Nickname'},
]
```

change your post.component.html like this:

```
<div  class="post"  *ngFor="let post of posts;" [attr.data-index]="post.id">
<a [title]="post.title" [routerLink]="['/post/', post.id]">
<div class="title">
  <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
  <span>Posted by: {{ post.author }}</span>
</div>
<div class="body">
  <p>{{ post.text }}</p>
</div>
```

then change your view-post.component.ts like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { POSTS } from 'src/app/mock-posts';
import { Post } from 'src/app/interface-post';   

@Component({
  selector: 'app-view-post',
  templateUrl: './view-post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view-post.component.scss']
})
export class ViewPostComponent implements OnInit {

  id: any;
  post: any;

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe((x: { get: (arg0: string) => any; }) => {
      this.id = x.get('id');
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.post = POSTS.find(x=>x.id == this.id);
  }

}
```

in the end add this to your view-post.component.html:

```
<div class="view-post">
  <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
  <p>{{ post.text }}</p>
</div>
```